# Looking for a school admin app for Ubuntu

Tags: 15.10

I am about to open a language school and would like to use Ubuntu there on the computers. Plus I badly need a school management tool (opening class, managing who signs up, where it is taught, students' and teachers' profiles, integrated website, payroll, HR...etc). Does anyone know of a free tool that could be used with Ubuntu? I am looking at "schooltool" which is supported on Ubuntu only, but I thought I would ask the users too. Hopefully someone has worked with something similar on Ubuntu.

Comment: some apps you can check out http://alternativeto.net/software/myskoolapp/?platform=linux

Comment: This Question might be more appropriate in the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever heard of Edubuntu? Edubuntu is an official Ubuntu flavor. Its target is Education, classrooms, schools and communities. It has quite a few tools for this, maybe one of them is what you're looking for? Take a look at

https://www.edubuntu.org/

It also uses the Unity Desktop, so you won't feel much difference in the userland.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SchoolTool](http://www.schooltool.org/), it's an open source, web based student information system designed for schools in the developing world, with strong support for translation, localization and automated deployment and updates via the Ubuntu Linux installer and package management system.

[image]

**Some Features :**

- Customizable student and teacher demographics and other personal data
- Contact management for teachers, students, and their guardians
- Teacher gradebooks
- Skill and outcomes based assessment
- Schoolwide assessment data collection and report card generation
- Class attendance and daily participation grades
- Calendars for the school, groups, individuals, and resource booking
- Tracking and management of student interventions

For more informations, see [Overview of Features](http://book.schooltool.org/features.html) page.

**Pros:** SchoolTool has a ton of features that largely appeal to teachers. It provides educators with what they need to run their classrooms (gradebooks, skill assessment documents, class attendance sheets, and daily participation journals), strong organization features (including a calendar that plugs in with popular calendar applications like Google Calendar), and a great report card generator. SchoolTool was made with Python, is largely secure, and is run on Linux Ubuntu.

**Cons:** SchoolTool is a great starting software for smaller schools, but it isn’t an all-inclusive piece of software. For example, schools will have to find other applications to do human resources, reporting, and financial management. SchoolTool is far more a tool for teachers than it is for administrators.

> For other solutions see : [The Top 6 Free and Open Source School Administration Software](http://blog.capterra.com/the-top-6-free-school-administration-software/)

### Installing SchoolTool :

To install or upgrade to SchoolTool 2.8, add the 2.8 PPA to your server’s sources list.

Using the command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:schooltool-owners/2.8
```

If you get an `add-apt-repository not found` error, install it:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

#### Installation :

Enter at the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install schooltool
```

After installation, the schooltool server can be accessed from the server at http://localhost:7080.

#### Upgrading SchoolTool :

To upgrade SchoolTool to a new *point* (2.6, 2.8, etc.), switch to a repository containing a newer version as described above, and enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

For more info :

- [Installing SchoolTool](http://book.schooltool.org/install-2_0.html)
- [How To Install SchoolTool Student Information System on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-schooltool-student-information-system-on-ubuntu-14-04)